# Files transfer to HDFS

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, flume

I need to bring the files (zip, csv, xml etc) from windows share location to HDFS. Which is the best approach ? I have kafka - flume - hdfs in mind. Please suggest the efficient way.

I tried getting the files to Kafka consumer.

producer.send(
                    new ProducerRecord(topicName,key,value),

Expect an efficient approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kafka is not designed to send files, only individual messages of up to 1MB, by default.

You can install NFS Gateway in Hadoop, then you should be able to copy directly from the windows share to HDFS without any streaming technology, only a scheduled script on the windows machine, or externally ran

Or you can mount the windows share on some Hadoop node, and schedule a Cron job if you need continuous file delivery - https://superuser.com/a/1439984/475508

Other solutions I've seen use tools like Nifi / Streamsets which can be used to read/move files
https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/26089/windows-share-nifi-hdfs-a-practical-guide.html

Comment: Thanks for the info. Actually I am splitting the files and sending to kafka as bytearray. Then in consumer end, I am converting those byte arrays to string, then writing to files. This way I am transferring the files from windows share to kafka consumer. Now my task is to transfer these files to HDFS. Sorry if my earlier question was bit confusing. Please suggest.

Comment: As long as you only have one topic partition and aren't sending multiple files into the same topic at the same time , that might work, but otherwise you can't guarantee your get your file splits back in the same order